# random number to UILabel in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, type-conversion

I have been looking everywhere for the answer to this but I cannot seem to figure out how to generate a random number and make it appear in a `UILabel` I created. I am very new to programming so sorry if this is a stupid question.

After getting millions of errors I have determined the function I usually use `self.titleLabel.text = @"WHATEVER"` will not work unless it is set equal to a string. This is my effort to convert my arc random integer to a string, but I keep getting errors.

```
NSInteger fish;
fish = (arc4random()%100)+1;

NSNumber *myNum = @(fish);
NSString* myString = @(fish);

self.titleLabel.text = myString;
```

(This time I am no longer getting errors on the viewcontroller.m page, but once the build succeeds I get a new error saying something is wrong with my main.m which I've never tried editing before.

This is what that looks like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

and the error says:

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT.

My output window just goes crazy.

Comment: FYI - See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug such crashes. Debugging a crash is one of the most important skills to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. You must set your label text to a string.

You want the `stringWithFormat` function.

This line:

NSString* myString = @(fish);

Makes no sense. It converts fish to an NSNumber, not a string. That code will generate a compiler warning about mismatched types, and then crash when you try to refer to myString. (Actually, looking at your code more closely, fish is already an NSNumber, so I'm not sure WHAT that code does exactly. Nothing good, in any case.)

You want something like this instead:

```
int fish = arc4random_uniform(100)+1;
self.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", fish];
```

The NSString class method stringWithFormat takes a format string and a variable number of parameters as inputs, and creates and returns a string as output. The "%d" format string gets replaced with an integer value.

### EDIT:

As rmaddy points out, you should use `arc4random_uniform()` instead of arc4random() with the modulo operator. Using the modulo operator results in "modulo bias" where some numbers are more common as a result than others.

Comment: Should also explain that using `arc4random_uniform` is better than `arc4random` and `%`.

Comment: OMG thank you so much Duncan, it works perfectly now!!!! I spent ~3 hours trying to figure this out and you solved my headache in 2 lines of code!! <3 REALLY APPRECIATE IT! :)

Comment: @ns993 Don't forget to accept answers that solve your questions.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest change is just to add stringValue to your myString line.  As is stands, you are creating another NSNumber - and you can see that if you set a breakpoint in the code, and look at the value of myString

```
NSString* myString = @(fish).stringValue;
```

Comment: Seems needlessly complicated to create an NSNumber and then create a string from that. It's also an extra object creation that is just discarded.

Comment: good point - I didn't notice there were two lines doing almost the same thing.  I still think when people are starting out (and for a long time after) it's useful to have more lines of painfully clear code, rather than trying to do everything in one complicated line of code, but your answer above is clear enough :-)

Comment: @Duncan C, use literal for NSNumber doesn't always mean allocated memory for NSObject. Read clang documentation about literals and search info about tagged pointers.

Comment: @ajjnix Its a fair bet that if you're using the `NSNumber` method `stringValue`, you've allocated an NSNumber object on the heap.

Comment: @ajjnix, I would like to read about how the LLVM compiler handles literals though, but couldn't find my way around the Clang site. Can you post  more specific link?

Comment: @Duncan C, http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html — Caveats. Also need read how work TaggedPointer classes. More information in this https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html

Answer (score 0):

Use something like that:
`NSString* myString = [NSStrirng stringWithFormat:"%i", fish];
self.titleLabel.text = myString;`

Comment: A good answer explains what the OP was doing wrong in addition to explaining offering a suggested fix.